# TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exclude_patterns'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Can't seem to get my app running. I'm following the tutorial from:

https://www.rithmschool.com/courses/flask-fundamentals/crud-with-flask

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 986, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 567, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 852, in run_command
    run_simple(
TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exclude_patterns'
```

I cannot seem to find anything on Google that talks about this specific error. These are the packages I have installed:

```
Package          Version
---------------- -------
click            8.1.3
Flask            2.1.3
Flask-Caching    1.8.0
Flask-Modus      0.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1
Flask-WTF        0.14.3
itsdangerous     2.1.2
Jinja2           3.1.2
MarkupSafe       2.1.1
pip              22.2.2
PyMySQL          1.0.2
setuptools       63.2.0
SQLAlchemy       1.4.39
Werkzeug         0.16.0
wheel            0.37.1
WTForms          3.0.1
```

I'm pinning to Werkzeug 0.16.0 because if I don't, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 214, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/raj/Documents/toys_proj/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_modus import Modus
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_modus.py", line 3, in <module>
    from werkzeug import url_decode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Yeah, but what do I do now? haha

Comment: post the code in this format:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error when trying to use Flask==2.1.0  I solved it by simply upgrading to Flask==2.2.0 which also asked for Werkzeug>=2.2.0,  so i included (installed) Werkzeug>=2.2.0 in my requirements file and that solved it.